# How do you match CJK filenames in BASH?

Tags: bash, cjk

I first attempted:

```
[$'\u4E00'-$'\u9FCC']
# Remember, if you, for example, specify [c-a]
# you will not get a range.
```

but only to realize that range is defined by collation order, not by their code points.

We also need to keep in mind that CJK characters are sorted by stroke count, then by radical.

So if we have a directory containing files, with some named using Latin characters and others named using CJK, and we want to manipulate those whose names are in CJK, how can we achieve this in BASH?

Comment: The post [Bracket expression (without ranges) matching unexpected character in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194157/bracket-expression-without-ranges-matching-unexpected-character-in-bash) has some interesting conversation in the first answer related to your question.